# UIAlertView send storyboard back to start

Tags: ios, storyboard, uialertview

iPhone app with a storyboard setup. Button on the initial view that links through to another view. I have added an alert to that button click so that when it is tapped the view changes and immediately the alert appears asking 'Do you want to continue? Yes No'

If they click yes the alert disappears, if they click no the storyboard should go back to the start.

This is what I've got so far and it doesn't work, nothing happens. I've tried multiple various solutions touted on SO but nothing is working so far. Removing the buttonindex check doesn't do anything.

I'd actually prefer this alert to appear even before the view changes but at the moment I have it displaying after the segue occurs which isn't ideal but if I could get it to segue back it would still be acceptable.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

   if (buttonIndex==1)     {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you've linked the button on your first view to the second view using a segue on the storyboard. To get it so that the UIAlertView pops up on the first view and then the segue is triggered depending on whether Yes or No is clicked you'll need to delete that segue and instead create it again by Ctrl-dragging from the first view (not the button) to the second view.

Create an IBAction for your button (if you haven't already) by Ctrl-dragging from your button to the views .h file and selecting Action. This should automatically create the method in the .m file - in that method you'll need to call your UIAlertView.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [myAlertView show];
}
```

Then the clickedButtonAtIndexMethod should be similar to what you had before. Instead of popping a controller (because the segue hasn't automatically happened) you'll want to call your segue using performSegueWithIdentifier.

```
- (void)alertView (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // They clicked Yes
    if (buttonIndex==1)     
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueName" sender:self];
    }
}
```

In regards to the clickedButtonAtIndex method not being called have you made the view a delegate of UIAlertView? So in your views .h file you need to have UIAlertViewDelegate like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```